# C: Read from stdin until Enter is pressed twice

Tags: c, io, stdin

Consider a simple program. It must take sequences of 5 numbers from stdin and print their sums. It is not stated how many lines of input will be taken, but program must terminate if newline character is taken twice (or Enter is pressed twice).

For example,

Input:

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3/n
/n
```

Output:

```
5
10
15




#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;
    int sum;
    while (/*condition*/)
    {
        scanf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);
        sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
        printf ("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The only problem is I don't know what condition must be in a while-loop. A little bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your scanf is wrong it should be  `scanf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5)`

Comment: Do the numbers have to be on separate lines?

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL thanks, i've editted the question

Comment: @teppic yes, they must

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `getc(stdin)` ([man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fgetc.html)) to read a single character from `stdin`, if it isn't a newline you can put it back with `ungetc(ch, stdin)` ([man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ungetc.html)) and use `scanf` to read your number.

```
int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int newlines = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while(1) {
        int ch = getc(stdin);
        if(ch == EOF) break;
        if(ch == '\n') {
            newlines++;
            if(newlines >= 2) break;
            continue;
        }

        newlines = 0;
        ungetc(ch, stdin);
        int x;
        if(scanf("%d", &x) == EOF) break;
        sum += x;
        n++;
        if(n == 5) {
            printf("Sum is %d\n", sum);
            n = 0;
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/y99Ns6

Comment: Good answer. One thing: `ch` should be an int, in order to test for EOF.

Comment: "if (n == 5) break;" won't this line break the loop after 5 numbers are taken?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev That's correct. It is how I understood your question; if it isn't what you want just remove it (and the declaration of `n`, and the printing of `n` at the end.)

Comment: ahhh, thanks, the point was that it must print all sums of all sequences with 5 numbers until Enter is pressed twice, edited the question

Comment: In that case, the `break` after `if(n == 5)` can be replaced with `{ printf("Sum is %d\n", sum); sum = n = 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could simply put the scanf call in the condition, and check if it succeeded in setting your variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, n3, n4. n5;
    int sum;
    while (scanf ("%d %d %d %d %d\n", n1, n2, n3, n4, n5) != EOF)
    {
        sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
        printf ("%d\n", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Couldn't test this code myself)

Comment: thanks, i have another question: if i don't know how many numbers will i take, what should i do? the point is my program must take the lines that correspond to the following property: first number is the shape of figure, 1 - circle, 2 - rectangle, then coordinates come (coordinate of center and radius vs. 4 coordinates of corners). my program must add up all areas, ignoring overlapping, etc. what should i do in this situation?