# Build a c program that reads an array

Tags: c, algorithm

i have this "test" let's say.. i need to solve this problem, it's not homework but i need it in order to pass a test.

I could need a little help, because i don't understand what i need to do.
I need the algorithm here!
So it goes:
The table below represents a labyrinth.
"1" means you cannot pass through that value, "0" means you can pass through that value.
"T" is the treasure to achieve and "H" is the entrance.
The coordinates are : H(3.1) , T(2.8).

-I need a program that reads a matrix A[1..M,1..N] which itself represents a labyrinth with elements [0,1] and also reads the H,T value.

It should print a way to the treasure  , if there is one, else it should say "No way to the treasure"he Matrix is:

```
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 0 0 0 1 0 T 0 1
    H 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
    1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: What did you try? How would you enumerate all the possible paths? Reading the array is probably the easiest... Did you read a good C programming book? Did you read a good algorithmics book?

Comment: Hi Basile!
So well, ok the idea is i know how to handle matrixes a little, but not in an advanced way.. i was hoping someone could give me an idea on how to do it.. then about the syntax i'd take care!

Comment: Seems a bit weird to classify this problem as reading an array. Look up depth first/breadth first/flood fill search for the algorithm, for reading the data in either use `scanf` directly if you know M/N or see for example this post for help reading in numbers and newlines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635686/c-read-from-stdin-until-enter-is-pressed-twice/15635911#15635911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Wall Follower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Wall_follower) approach. You need to have a variable where you store the direction you are looking at (left, right, up, down). Then you keep going in that direction until you hit a wall. When you're at a wall, you keep turning left until you can continue walking. Do this until you're at the target.

Or in pseudo code:

```
var walkingDirection = up;
while (not at target)
    if (next field in walkingDirection is not a wall)
        go to next field in walkingDirection
    else
        turn right
    end if
end while
```

This will however fail in mazes that are not simply connected (read that link).

An other, slightly more difficult approach might be the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm).

Comment: This looks good...thanks :) the wall is supposed to be "1".. well i'll check on it